# Is it a good practice to make a web method synchronized when used by different threads?

Tags: java, web-services, synchronization, eclipselink

I asked a similar question in Code Review forum but was suggested to ask that question here. 
I am wondering about the `synchronized` keyword in the web-method below. Since `setPerson` is called from a thread pool (meaning that different threads can call it), I should syncronize it in someway. The thead pool is used by EclipseLink when my client is doing SOAP calls to the method. My question is if it is a good practice to make a web method `synchronized` or can I do the synchronization with `em.lock(person, WRITE)`?

```
@Override
public synchronized void setPerson(Person person) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersonLibPU");            
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(); 
    if(!em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
       em.getTransaction().begin();
    }
    try {
         person.setPersonId(getLastInsertedId() + 1); // Get the last inserted ID and increment it by 1
         em.merge(person);
         em.getTransaction().commit();  
         emf.getCache().evict(Person.class);                    
    } catch (Exception ex) {
         if(em.getTransaction().isActive())
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I added one more row in the code above where I set the primary key value of the person object. That is what the synchronization is made for, not for any shared java objects. I need to synchronize it so two threads cannot get the same primary key.

Comment: The code only uses local variables. Why would you want to synchronize it. Side not: You shouldn't create a new EntityManagerFactory in each method. Create it once, and always reuse the unique instance.

Comment: Yes, the variables are local but it is the database transaction I am afraid of. Two or more threads can potentially call ´setPerson()´ and write the same primary key since the PK:s are not auto incremented. So the synchronization is not for shared java object, but rather for the database access.

Comment: Then you'll need to handle this possibility by handling the potential exception that might be thrown. Synchronization is not the right solution, since it won't handle the case when the person is saved by another method, or the person is saved by another application, or the person is saved by another JVM in the cluster.

Comment: You are right if the person is saved by another application or another JVM, but if all methods that handles Person objects are synchronized, then it shouldn´t matter what method that persists a person. Right? I will remove the synchronization and handle the exception that might occur in the catch block, as you suggested. :-)

Comment: No. All the methods would need to be synchronized **on the same object**.

Comment: @JBNizet: Yes. But if I synchronize the method like the code sample above, then the object itself will be synchronized. So that would work if a Person object is just handled from that class (within the synchronized methods)? But not work if the database is accessed from another application or JVM. Right?

Comment: Whatever the synchronization technique you use, it will only work in a non-clustered deployment, where only one server inserts rows in this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're possibly asking the wrong question. Synchronization won't help you here, as the only part that has concurrency concerns is `getLastInsertedId()`: you wouldn't want two methods to get hold of the same value and try persisting an instance with that ID.

Synchronizing `setPerson` would only solve the problem if it's the only method that persists a `Person`.

If possible use the underlying data-store's auto-incrementing functionality; failing that does your ORM solution perform context-wide ID allocation? The last resort would be to have a method of `getNextId` that *could* be synchronized and returns an incremented value. This may end up with non-contiguous ID sequences in the database (`getNextId` won't know if the persist operation succeeded), but this reduces the scope of the locking.

As JB Nizet points out, the ID-allocation needs to be persisted and made available in some fashion that is available to all clients of this data store. If you had two instances of your application persisting `Person` instances, you would need to ensure that they share an ID-allocator.